# JSP can not access object property

Tags: java, jsp

I have the object Project:

```
public class Project {
    public static int projectid = 0;

    private int id;

    private String name;
    private String description;

    private Category category;

    public DonationLogic donation;

    private String link;
    private String questionsAndAnswers;

    //methods
}
```

And DonationLogic (is the property of Project):

```
public class DonationLogic {
    private int totalAmount;
    private int daysLeft;
    private double collectAmount;
    private int id;
    private String donatorname;
    private int daonatorcardid;
    private static int donationid = 0;

    //methods
}
```

I try to access Project properties in JSP:

```
<c:forEach var="project" items="${projects}">
            <c:out value="${project.name}"/></a></br>
            Name: <c:out value="${project.name}"/></br>
            Description: <c:out value="${project.description}"/></br>
            TotalAmount/CollectAmount: <c:out value="${project.donation.totalAmount}/${project.donation.collectAmount}"/></br>
            DaysLeft: <c:out value="${project.donation.daysLeft}"/></br>
            Category: <c:out value="${project.category.name}"/></br>
        </c:forEach>
```

All code works but the lines with `project.donation.XXX`. 
The Error is:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'donation' not found on
>   type data.Project

What can I do? Line with `project.category.name` works
I noticed that property donation is public whereas other are private. Maybe the problem is in it?

Comment: Does "donation" has get and setter?

Comment: Within Project object - no.

Comment: No, in "DonationLogic" class.

Answer (score 2):

Add a getter method:

```
public DonationLogic getDonation {
    return this.donation;
}
```

You can also add something like this in the jsp to see what your objects looks like:

```
PROJECTS=${projects}<br/>
<c:forEach var="project" items="${projects}">
            PROJECT=${project}<br/>
            <c:out value="${project.name}"/></a></br>
            Name: <c:out value="${project.name}"/></br>
            Description: <c:out value="${project.description}"/></br>
            TotalAmount/CollectAmount: <c:out value="${project.donation.totalAmount}/${project.donation.collectAmount}"/></br>
            DaysLeft: <c:out value="${project.donation.daysLeft}"/></br>
            Category: <c:out value="${project.category.name}"/></br>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: So it means that JSP can not access properties without getters?

Comment: How in this case JSP can access private properties? No way?

Answer (score 0):

```
${project.donation.daysLeft}
```

This is a JSP Expression Language Syntax. EL works on getters setters. So you must have getter method to access the bean property. Below is the quote from [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html#bnahx)

> a property must at least have an accessor method called getProperty,
>   where Property is the name of the property that can be referenced by
>   an expression.

So, `project` should have `getDonation()` and `donation` bean should have `getDaysLeft()` getter method for this EL expression to work